# Pulling data from uploaded text file into django database

Tags: python, django

**EDIT: Updated question to make it more clear what I am trying to attempt!**

I am brand new to Django (using version 1.11.1) with a MySQL database.

Schema: **testdb**
Table: **output** (consisting of 3 columns - header1, header2 and header3)

**Views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'], str(request.FILES['file']))
        return HttpResponse("Successful")

    return HttpResponse("Failed")

def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):
    for s in file.read().split(','):
        myobject = output(fileData=s)
        myobject.save()
```

How would I go about, on the uploading of a plain text file the information is split using a "," as the delimiter and then populated directly into the MySQL database.

So for example I have a text file which contains:

1. Andy,72%,Pass
2. Craig,44%,Fail

I want this to end up in a mysql database as 2 rows of data under each seperate heading but without the ","

Comment: so you need to store according to your example, three different records in the database? or one row with three files in a field?

Comment: three different records into the database

Comment: ok ,then it's like @Ryan W pointed out in his answer below. You need to create a new object for every word.

Comment: The best way is to execute the `LOAD DATA INFILE` or `COPY TO` or similar CSV loading command for your database using django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model looks something like this:

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    fileData = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
def handle_uploaded_file(file, filename):
    for s in file.read().split(','):
        myobject = MyModel(fileData=s)
        myobject.save()
```

Comment: This gives me "create() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)" I am assuming this is because its counting the "," as an arguement?

Comment: Thanks Ryan, finally I am sure I am just being really stupid here but apparently now I get a "TypeError" of 'field2' is an invalid keyword argument for this function but theres nothing wrong with 'field1' as a keyword?... doesnt seem to matter what i call them, its always an invalid arguement

Comment: I misunderstood your problem. I thought you wanted to create 1 db record with 3 field from the file instead of 3 records with one field. I'll update my answer

Comment: This doesn't scale

Comment: There might be some confusion on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to write to a file inside the django app directory or store the contents of the file in the database?

Comment: Store the contents of a text file in a database. (Apologies for the confusion) but I need to break the text file apart based on the "," before its stored

Comment: No worries about the confusion. My revised answer should accomplish what you're wanting. The code you originally posted was attempting to have django write the file to its directory (usually a bad idea). The recommendation by @e4c5 might get better performance but is a bit more advanced especially if you're new to Django. Just go with what I shared and if you find you need to write to the db more quickly, look into what he/she suggested

Comment: you should reallyl be using bulk_create instead of saving them one by one.

Comment: @e4ct yes, bulk_create would save you some sql transactions but considering it's OP's first day of Django, performance tweaks should come after learning the basics.

Comment: you may be missing `request`as the first argument of the method

Comment: @Tushortz if you're refering to `handle_uploaded_file`, it is used by OP and Django docs as a helper function and not an actually view callback

Comment: @RyanW So I know there was some confusion yesterday but I think we had it correct the first time, I have a mysql database connected with django with the schema "random" and a table "output" in that schema.. I am trying to split the file on "," into 1 row with 3 sets of data in that row... That aside, When using the script you provided, on upload I get "Table 'random.postoutput_output' doesn't exist" (which is correct it doesnt, but random.output does, so why is it adding the "postoutput_"?

Comment: Could you share you Model class? I think it might help further clear up some confusion.